# scala parse json which has List of maps

Tags: json, scala

I have some json when I parsed that it is returning stucture Some(List(Map...))

How to match with something and get the values

Below is the code I tried, I need to get all the map values

```
 import scala.util.parsing.json._
 val result = JSON.parseFull("[{\"start\":\"starting\",\"test\":123,\"test2\":324,\"end\":\"ending\"}]")


 result match {
   case Some(map: Map[String, Any]) => { println(map) 

   }

   case None => println("Parsing failed")
   case other => println("Unknown data structure: " + other)
 }
```

but its printing non matching

```
 Unknown data structure: Some(List(Map(start -> starting, test -> 123, test2 -> 324, end -> ending)))
```

Comment: What you put is expected result of `JSON.parseFull`. Your JSON is an example is an array, which will be parsed as a `List`, then parsed as a `Map` for the objects inside the array. https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.9.3/scala/util/parsing/json/JSON$.html

Comment: To add to @AndrewNolan, here is how you pattern match it:

     result match {
        case Some(List(m:Map[_, _])) => println(m)
     }

Comment: How to iterate that List get the map objects ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of **type erasure**, you cannot pattern match on generics types. `List`, `Map`, `Option` are generic containers, and in runtime compiler will erase types of these generic containers. e.g. `List[String]`, `String` will be erased and type will be `List[_]`.

```
case Some(map: List[Map[String, Any]]) => println(map)
```

In your case above case, if result is `val result: Option[Any] = Some(List(12))` i.e. `12`, which type is `Int` and not `Map[String, Any]`, compiler will still match the `result` with above case even it expects `Map[String, Any]]` as type of `List`.

**So, Whats going on?**

Its all because of **type erasure**. The compiler will erase all the types and it won't have any type information at runtime unless you use reflection. That means:
`case Some(map: List[Map[String, Any]]) => println(map)`  is essentially `case Some(map: List[_]) => println(map)` and therefore, match will success for any type parameter of `List` e.g. `List[Map[String, Any]]`, `List[Map[String, Int]]`, `List[String]`, `List[Int]` etc.

Therefore, In case you need to match on such generic container, you have to resolve each container and its nested subtypes explicitly.

```
def resolve(result: Any): Unit = result match {
    case Some(res) if res.isInstanceOf[List[_]] && res.asInstanceOf[List[_]].isEmpty  => println("Empty List.")  //Some(List())
    case Some(res) if res.isInstanceOf[List[_]] && !res.asInstanceOf[List[_]].exists(p => p.isInstanceOf[Map[_, _]] && p.asInstanceOf[Map[_, _]].nonEmpty) => println("List is not empty but each item of List is empty Map.")  //Some(List(Map(), Map()))
    case Some(res) if res.isInstanceOf[List[_]] && res.asInstanceOf[List[_]].filter(p => p.isInstanceOf[Map[_, _]] && p.asInstanceOf[Map[_, _]].nonEmpty).map(_.asInstanceOf[Map[_,_]]).exists(p => {p.head match {case e if e._1.isInstanceOf[String] && e._2.isInstanceOf[Any] => true; case _ => false}})  => println("Correct data.") // Some(List(Map("key1"-> 1), Map("key2" -> 2)))
    case None => println("none")
    case other => println("other")
}

val a: Option[Any] = Some(List())
val b: Option[Any] = Some(List(Map(), Map()))
val c: Option[Any] = Some(List(Map("key1"-> 1), Map("key2" -> 2)))
val d: Option[Any] = None
val e: Option[Any] = Some("apple")

resolve(a) // match first case
resolve(b) // match second case
resolve(c) // match third case
resolve(d) // match fourth case
resolve(e) // match fifth case
```

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out the return type is actually `Option[List[Map[String, Any]]]` so you need to unpick this. However you cannot do this with a single `match` because of type erasure, so you need to do nested matches to ensure that you have the correct type. This is really tedious, so I thoroughly recommend using something like the `Extraction.extract` function in `json4s` that will attempt to match your JSON to a specific Scala type:

```
type ResultType = List[Map[String, Any]]

def extract(json: JValue)(implicit formats: Formats, mf: Manifest[ResultType]): ResultType =
  Extraction.extract[ResultType](json)
```

If you must do it by hand, it looks something like this:

```
result match {
  case Some(l: List[_]) =>
    l.headOption match {
      case Some(m) =>
        m match {
          case m: Map[_,_] =>
            m.headOption match {
              case Some(p) =>
                p match {
                  case (_: String, _) =>
                    m.foreach(println(_))
                  case _ => println("Map key was not String")
                }
              case _ => println("Map was empty")
            }
          case _ => println("List did not contain a Map")
        }
      case _ => println("Result List was empty")
    }
  case _ => println("Parsing failed")
}
```

Comment: This is the best approach to pattern match generic containers avoiding type erasure.

Answer (score -2):

Your output is `Option[List[Map[String, Any]]]`, not `Option[Map[String, Any]]`. match on the List and you'll be fine:

```
import scala.util.parsing.json._
val result = JSON.parseFull("[{\"start\":\"starting\",\"test\":123,\"test2\":324,\"end\":\"ending\"}]")

val l: List[Map[String, Any]] = result match {
  case Some(list: List[Map[String, Any]]) => list
  case _ => throw new Exception("I shouldn't be here") // whatever for a non-match
}
```

Then you can `map` (if you want a non-Unit return type)/ `foreach` (if you don't care about a Unit return type) on that List and do whatever you want it:

```
l.foreach(println)
l.map(_.toString) // or whatever you want ot do with the Map
```

Comment: This won't work. e.g. `val result: Option[List[Any]] = Some(List(1))` it will still match first case even 1 is Int not Map because of type erasure.

Comment: Ah darn, I always forget about type erasure. [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52551784/8230810) (ie match on the Option, then match on the List, then match on the Map, etc.) would be best.